# Basis words in search engine

Tags: search-engine

I wondered that if there is a rule for the selection of basis words in search engine when building inverted index. I know that generally stop words will not be indexed. But how about others? I'm confused...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean stemming? Some search engines use that. It means that all words are truncated, so `walk`, `walks`, `walked` and `walking` will all be indexed as `walk`. The same is applied on queries before running the search. It results in more hits, since a search for `walking in the woods` will also mach “a `walk in the woods`”.

Comment: Not just stemming. I mean we cannot index every word in the web because it's too big, right? So which words should be indexed and which should be ignored? Is there a common rule?

Comment: Search modules *do* index _every_ word in every document they digest. There are compression techniques to reduce the hard disk space needed, however these binary indices quickly grow huge. I think every search engine operator has its own rules by experience for some exclusions. For example, if I would have to design a search engine by myself I would exclude strings that do never appear more than once from OCR-read documents, but that would be just my own decision. I also know a search engine which only indexes words that are part of gramatically valid sentences. But there is no _general_ rule.